# Cannot accept meeting invite in Thunderbird Lightning when email address is not in attendance fields (sent to mailing list)

Tags: email, thunderbird, lightning

When sending a meeting invite to co-workers, we generally send them to an email list we are all subscribed to.  Because of this, when an invite comes in, I sometimes cannot accept/deny the request due to the fact that it wasn't sent to my email specifically, but instead was sent to that email address.

How can I make sure that I can accept/deny any email requests that come into my inbox?